# Typical sequences and entropy

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, information-theory, large-deviation-theory, typical-sequences

The book "Probability, Random Processes, and Statistical Analysis" (written by Hisashi Kobayashi and Brian L. Mark and William Turin), talks about the role of entropy in characterising typical sequences (page 257). It says that in a coin tossing experiment:

> When we change the experiment of fair coin tossing to that of an
> unfair coin that lands on head with probability $β$, then a sequence
> that contains $nβ$ heads becomes a typical sequence, and the number of
> such typical sequences approaches $2^{nH(β)}$ for large $n$. Each
> typical sequence will occur with probability $2^{−nH(β)}$. There are
> $2^n$ possible distinct sequences. The difference $2^n − 2^{nH(β)}$ is
> the number of nontypical sequences, and the total probability of such
> sequences becomes negligibly small for sufficiently large $n$.

where $H(\beta)=-\beta \log_2\beta-(1-\beta)\log_2(1-\beta)$.

However if I calculate the probability of a nontypical sequence as number of favourable events over the number of possible events, I have:
\begin{equation}
P(\mathrm{nontypical})=\frac{2^n − 2^{nH(β)}}{2^n}=1-2^{n(H(β)-1)}
\end{equation}
which goes to $1$ as $n\to\infty$ since $0\leqslant H(β)\leqslant1$ with the logarithms understood in base $2$.

What's wrong with my calculation? It directly contradicts the Authors and this sounds suspicious :-)

Comment: The *proportion* of non-typical sequences goes to $1$, but their total *probability* goes to zero.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! But why the "frequentistic" probability formulation doesn't work here? And how can I calculate their total probability that you are mentioning?

Answer (score 4):

I don't much like the quoted paragraph.

First: when we say that a sequence is "typical", we must say with "typical with respect of what". It's typical with respect to the mean if the sample mean equals (approximately) the true mean. It's typical with respect to the entropy if the "sample entropy" $-\log(p(X^{[n]})/n$ equals (approximately) the true entropy $H(X)$. The phrase

> then a sequence that contains $\beta n$ heads becomes a
>   typical sequence.

confuses both concepts. That would apply to the "typical with respect to the mean" concept - but we are speaking of "typical with respect to the entropy" here. (The difference is most evident in the fair case: here, all sequences are typical with respect to the entropy, but only those having -approximately- as many zeroes as ones are typical with respect to the mean).

Second: notice the word "approximately". The concept of typicality is always relative to an $\epsilon$. The quoted sentence, again, is confusing in this regard.

Now, to address your doubt: It's still true that the number of typical sequences (with respect to the entropy!) is approximately $2^{nH(\beta)}$. But your assertion

$$P(nontypical)=\frac{2^n − 2^{nH(\beta)}}{2^n}=1-2^{n(H(\beta)-1)}$$
is wrong. What you are evaluating there is the proportion of non typical sequences, *counting* them, over the total. That's not a probability, because they are not equiprobable.

Precisely, the essence of the thing ([AEP property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property)) is:

- Typical sequences happen almost always (the total probability is almost 1)
- Typical sequences are few (as a proportion of the total number) (unless the source has maximal entropy - all symbols equiprobable).

Updated: typical sequences are (approximately) equiprobable, indeed, because of their definition: the probability of each one is (approx) $2^{-nH}$. And because we know that their total probability is (approx) 1, this leads to their total count being $2^{nH}$

Comment: Thanks for your answer! The comparison you do regarding typicality for mean and entropy is very deep. Regarding the calculation, are the typical sequences equiprobable? If so then the probability of having a typical sequence could be written as $P(typical)=2^{nH(\beta)}/2^n$ and the probability for all the typical sequences is $\sum P(typical)=2^{nH(\beta)}/2^n \cdot 2^{nH(\beta)}$. Now this last probability should go to 1 somehow?

Comment: See update. Again, your $P(typical)=2^{nH(\beta)}/2^n$ is wrong. Typical sequences are indeed equiprobable, but the others are not, so you can't evaluate the probabilty as a ratio. The fact that the total probability of typical sequences tend to one cannot be derived in this way, it's a consequence of the law of large numbers. See eg the classic textbook of Cover & Thomas. Once you accept this (and only them) you can deduce that their number is $2^{nH}$.

Comment: Ok! But how do we know that the total probability of the typical sequences, that is the sum of the probability of all the typical sequences to happen, is equal to 1? (I think it should be a consequence of the law of large numbers that we are implicitly using but I'm not sure)

Comment: I already told you: it's a consequence of the law of large numbers https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_equipartition_property

Comment: I've checked the book you were mentioning and it's quite clear, thanks! Just to make sure that I've understood, since the typical sequences are approx equiprobable, is it possible to say that roughly the probability of observing a "specific" typical sequence is $P(\text{specific typical sequence})=2^{-nH}=1/n_T$ where $n_T$ is the number of typical sequences? So this implies $n_T=2^{nH}$